# Django Rest required parameters in URL

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I'm using django rest framework.
Here is my code:

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/show', UserShow.as_view()),
]
```

**view.py:**

```
class UserShow(ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        if user_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=user_id)
        return queryset
```

I want to get values from url like this: 
`/users/show?user_id=1` or `/users/show?username=mike`.

**Either an `user_id` or `username` must be required parameter.** How can I control it in class based views?

With my code if I'm sending the request with wrong parameter name `/users/show?user111name=mike` or simple `/users/show` the view of course response me with `queryset = User.objects.all()` and lists all the users. I don't need that. I need if required parameters are `None` response with 404.

I can get needed result with **function based view**:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def users(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        username = request.GET.get('username', None)
        user_id = request.GET.get('user_id', None)

        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        elif user_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=user_id)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "required field not found."},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        if not queryset.exists():
            return Response({"status": "not found."},
                            status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

But how can I do it with **generic** class based views?

Comment: You should take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36505792/drf-base-viewset-for-query-param-validation

Comment: Could you please explain to me why you are using ListAPIView to get *single* object? There is a RetrieveAPIView dedicated for such a use, plus you can have username or id used as part of the url not query..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class UserIdRetrieve(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    
class UserUsernameRetrieve(UserIdRetrieve):
     lookup_field = 'username'
```

and in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/(?P<pk>\d+)/', UserIdRetrieve.as_view()), 
    url(r'^users/by-username/(?P<username>\w+)/', UserUsernameRetrieve.as_view())
]
```

if your url structure is a must, small change to above:

```
class UserIdRetrieve(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        if 'username' in self.request.query_params:
            filter_kwargs = {'username': self.request.query_params['username']}
        elif 'user_id' in self.request.query_params:
             filter_kwargs = {'id': self.request.query_params['user_id']}
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Missing required parameters')

        obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)

        # May raise a permission denied
        self.check_object_permissions(self.request, obj)

        return obj
```

and in urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^users/show', UserRetrieve.as_view())
]
```

Comment: I'm using `ListAPIView` because `RetrieveAPIView` requires `pk` as argument but in my case I'm not getting it from url in classic django way, due to using `query_params`. Of course your variant will work, but take a look at required url format again, it's not exactly what I need.

Comment: added version that matches your url structure

Comment: I would return `400` Bad Request response in case of missing required parameter not `404`

Answer (score 1):

```
class UserShow(ListAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)

        if username is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        if user_id is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(pk=user_id)
        return queryset

    def list(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username', None)
        user_id = self.request.query_params.get('user_id', None)
        if not (username or user_id):
            return Response({"status": "Required field not found."},
                                        status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
        return super(UserShow, self).list(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

Comment: It's working but is there more DRY way? Anyway I'll mark your answer as solution for now.

Comment: ListAPIView should not be used for retrieving single instance